# Is it possible to get the Instagram news feed through the API?

Tags: instagram, feed, instagram-api

When you open the Instagram APP you can look at your news feed where you can see that someone is now following you, likes or has commented on a certain photo.

When I look at the Instagram API (http://instagram.com/developer/) I can retrieve likes and comments when I request a certain media ID. However in order to know if someone has commented on a photo of mine I would need to scan all the photo's and request it's comments to check if any new comments have been made.

Does anyone know of a better way? Help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this available through their API. It would be nice if one of the real-time subscriptions provided something like this, but there is not one for media objects.

Comment: Yes my first pick would be to look there as well. Will indeed be nice if they could add such a feature, would prevent a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it helps, content for "Following" tab is available at http://instagram.com/api/v1/news/, and "News" tab at http://instagram.com/api/v1/news/inbox/ (you need to be logged in to your account).
All URLs point to internal instagram:// protocol so you would need to replace them when parsing and there seem to be no pagination options.

Comment: Actually that did help. I will just parse it, tho any version updates may screw it up. So I hope they will still come up with an API some day, but it's definitely something thank you.

Comment: If you want to get your feed via the command line give a look at https://github.com/mapio/instagram-news-cli